# STL/ranges algorithm to calculate weighted average

Tags: c++, stl, weighted-average, range-v3

Assume I have a vector of grades, where the grade is

```
struct Grade{
   const int grade;
   const int ECTS; // weight
};
```

Is there a STL/range-v3 algorithm/algorithms that enable me to do this?

I know I could do it with `std:: accumulate` with some fancy type as an accumulator(that remembers the sum of weights), but I am looking for a simpler alternative if one exists.

Comment: Constrained numeric algorithms are currently being developed: [P1813](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1813r0.pdf). They'll enable something like: `ranges::inner_product(grades, grades, 0, {}, {}, &Grade::grade, &Grade::ECTS);`

Answer (score 17):

The `Grade` type itself is fancy enough to act as the accumulator type.

```cpp
auto [grade_sum, ects] = std::accumulate(
    grages.begin(), grades.end(), Grade {0,0}, 
    [] (Grade acc, Grade g) -> Grade {
        return { g.grade*g.ECTS + acc.grade,
                 g.ECTS         + acc.ECTS  };
});
// auto average_grade = grade_sum/ects;
```

*C++17 structured binding can be replaced by `std::tie` if necessary.*

Comment: Probably `auto average_grade = double(grade_sum) / ects`.

Comment: That is is a possibility indeed. Thanks for fixing the accumulator/value order by the way ;)

Answer (score 7):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), it might be:

```
auto average = ranges::inner_product(grades, grades, 0, {}, {}, &Grade::grade, &Grade::ECTS)
        / double(ranges::accumulate(grades, 0, {}, &Grade::ECTS));
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01b2d559626fa547)

Comment: Currently, the compilation time is a show-stopper. https://godbolt.org/z/I1_kGh vs https://godbolt.org/z/eVvMJz or 14448ms (ranges::inner_product) vs 3890ms (std::accumulate)